# Change Display Size of Images Rendered from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am rendering numpy arrays stored in a pandas DataFrame.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import HTML
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import matplotlib as mpl
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity

def image_formatter(arr):
    cm = mpl.cm.get_cmap("viridis")
    i = rescale_intensity(cm(arr)[...,:3], out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
    im = Image.fromarray(i)
    im.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.LANCZOS)
    
    with BytesIO() as buffer:
        im.save(buffer, "jpeg")
        enc = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()
    return f'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{enc}">'

def display_profile(d):
    with pd.option_context("display.max_colwidth", 1000):
        return HTML(d.to_html(formatters=dict(img=image_formatter), escape=False))
  

digits = [np.reshape(x, (8,8)) for x in datasets.load_digits()["data"]][:5]
testdf = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [10,20,30,40,50], "img": digits})
display_profile(testdf)
```

[image]

How do I change size of my thumbnails, because they are pretty small?

I tried changing the thumbnail size, to change the `max_colwidth` option of pandas and to add a `style` option to the HTML `<img>` tag, but nothing worked. Any ideas? Do I maybe need to change some hidden Jupyter notebook option?

Comment: Where is np and pd defined?

Comment: Would you be so kind and grant the bounty, if I helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem of your `image_formatter` function.

In the last line of this function instead of:

```
im.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.LANCZOS)
```

write:

```
im = im.resize((500,500))
```

the whole function should be:

```
def image_formatter(arr):
    cm = mpl.cm.get_cmap("viridis")
    i = rescale_intensity(cm(arr)[...,:3], out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
    im = Image.fromarray(i)
    im = im.resize((500,500))
```

Although, I think that `im.resize((20,20))` will fit just perfectly :)